# Best practices for tuning virtual hosts

Tags: linux, vmware-vsphere, centos6, rhel6

While digging around to find resources on tuning virtual hosts I found an article on VMWares knowledgebase [about changing the I/O scheduler](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2011861).

What else should be considered for improving performance/reliability? Are there any community guides (VMWare, Redhat?) that detail such settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a lot of experience regarding this, this are my suggestions:

- Use VMWare Tools
- Disable unnecessary services from your host
- Use paravirtualized hardware where possible.
- If you really don't need access time updates (on your partition), then disable it.
- As you said, change the scheduler on noop
- Try to play with overcommit memory and swappines
- When you create the VM choose for a fully allocated disk
- Use VM snapshots only if necessary

  http://lonesysadmin.net/linux-virtual-machine-tuning-guide/
  http://www.vmware.com/pdf/Perf_Best_Practices_vSphere4.0.pdf
  http://communities.vmware.com/thread/146002